# Auto-Completing JTextField and Arrow Keys

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextfield

I'm trying to build a `javax.swing.JTextField` with `javax.swing.JList` for auto-completing like *Google*.

- When a write a word, `Google` show several *matches* and

  - when a *press* the   <kbd>▼</kbd>   I can select some *match* using   <kbd>▲</kbd>    and   <kbd>▼</kbd>   and
  - can edit my input with   <kbd>◀</kbd>  and   <kbd>▶</kbd>  .
  - When I press     <kbd>Enter</kbd>          key search the content in the box.
  - When a press <kbd>Esc</kbd> the box change to the original input.

My aplication is about the [Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible) and I want to looking for a particular word when I'm studying the Word. I have seen the [Java2sAutoTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) but don't have this particular behavior with the arrow keys.

Comment: Could you extend the JTextField and give it a JList as a member, then manage the key presses manually from the JTextField?

Also, wouldn't the drop-down list get cut off at the edge of the container? Swing components being lightweight 'n' all.

Comment: @mKorbel If there is a better solution, I would like to know more. Actually, I'm looking for a behavior similar to Google, not necessarily with `JList`.

Comment: @Paul Vargas well I'll look at that, I think that this question could be very simple for coding

Comment: @mKorbel Currently I have a `JTextField` without customization within a `JToolBar`. I have seen an example in book Swing Hacks. I'm reviewing it because it has a small problem in the event `CaretListener` in the example.

Comment: answer by @george_h could be correct and best of all here,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This needs a custom coded component. Definitely a class that extends JTextField and in that class you have a JPopupMenu that will contain your JList. You will have to position the JPopupMenu right under the text field so that it looks like 1 component.

Your next trick is to filter as you type. I usually do this using Java6 TableRowSorter coupled with a JTable to which I pre-fill it with data. You're gonna need some change listeners on the JTextField and intercept each key typed and fetch your data.

1. Key pressed
2. Perform query in DB (or some data storage to get similar entries)
3. Populate JTable with those entires
4. Set RowFilter with regex based on JTextField entry to filter through retrieved data
5. Manage your actions with key listeners

**EDIT**

I whipped up a sample swing app to show what I stated. This is a copy/paste example and should work right off the bat (need JDK 1.6+). I basically got what you wanted and I put comments in places where I tell you to fill in the blanks.. like for example the Escape key event is consumed and you can do whatever you want with it.

The method initTableModel() just initializes the table model with data. Normally you would want to dynamically populate the table model with data from a database or something. A lot could be tweaked, but this is for example sake ;) So this should be a good enough example for you to modify to your complete your goal. Any more than this and you have to pay me $$$ :)

```
package test.text.googleclone;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class SearchAutoFillTest {

private JFrame frame = null;
private JTextField searchField = null;
private JPopupMenu popup = null;

private JTable searchTable = null;
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> rowSorter = null;
private DefaultTableModel searchTableModel = null;

public SearchAutoFillTest() {
    searchTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    initTableModel();

    rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(searchTableModel);
    searchTable = new JTable(searchTableModel);
    searchTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
    searchTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    searchTable.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    searchTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    searchTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    searchTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(775, 100));
    searchTable.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);

    searchField = new JTextField();
    searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            showPopup(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            showPopup(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            showPopup(e);
        }
    });

    searchField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int code = e.getKeyCode();
            switch(code)
            {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                {
                    cycleTableSelectionUp();
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                {
                    cycleTableSelectionDown();
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                {
                    //Do whatever you want here
                    break;
                }

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                {
                    //Do whatever you want here
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });

    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE");
    searchField.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, "ESCAPE");
    searchField.getActionMap().put("ESCAPE", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Do what you wish here with the escape key.
        }
    });

    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    popup.add(searchTable);
    popup.setVisible(false);
    popup.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

    JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    searchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
    searchPanel.add(searchField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    frame.add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    center(frame);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private final void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> rf = null;

    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(getFilterText(), 0);
    }
    catch(PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }

    rowSorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}

private final String getFilterText() {
    String orig = searchField.getText();
    return "("+orig.toLowerCase()+")|("+orig.toUpperCase()+")";
}

private void showPopup(DocumentEvent e) {
    if(e.getDocument().getLength() > 0) {
        if(!popup.isVisible()) { 
            Rectangle r = searchField.getBounds();
            popup.show(searchField, (r.x-4), (r.y+16));
            popup.setVisible(true);
        }

        newFilter();
        searchField.grabFocus();

    }
    else {
        popup.setVisible(false);
    }
}

private void cycleTableSelectionUp() {
    ListSelectionModel selModel = searchTable.getSelectionModel();
    int index0 = selModel.getMinSelectionIndex();
    if(index0 > 0) {
        selModel.setSelectionInterval(index0-1, index0-1);
    }
}

private void cycleTableSelectionDown() {
    ListSelectionModel selModel = searchTable.getSelectionModel();
    int index0 = selModel.getMinSelectionIndex();
    if(index0 == -1) {
        selModel.setSelectionInterval(0, 0);
    }
    else if(index0 > -1) {
        selModel.setSelectionInterval(index0+1, index0+1);
    }
}

private void initTableModel() {
    String[] columns = new String[] {"A"};
    String[][] data = new String[][]
    {
        new String[] {"a"},
        new String[] {"aa"},
        new String[] {"aaab"},
        new String[] {"aaabb"},
        new String[] {"aaabbbz"},
        new String[] {"b"},
        new String[] {"bb"},
        new String[] {"bbb"},
        new String[] {"bbbbbbb"},
        new String[] {"bbbbbbbeee"},
        new String[] {"bbbbbbbeeexxx"},
        new String[] {"ccc"},
        new String[] {"cccc"},
        new String[] {"ccccc"},
        new String[] {"cccccaaaa"},
        new String[] {"ccccccaaaa"},
    };

    searchTableModel.setDataVector(data, columns);
}

private void center(Window w) {
    int screenWidth  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    int screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;

    int windowWidth = w.getWidth();
    int windowHeight = w.getHeight();

    if (windowHeight > screenHeight) {
        return;
    }

    if (windowWidth > screenWidth) {
        return;
    }

    int x = (screenWidth - windowWidth) / 2;
    int y = (screenHeight - windowHeight) / 2;

    w.setLocation(x, y);
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    new SearchAutoFillTest();
}
}
```

Comment: I find it very interesting. I'll try and send you feedback.

Comment: It really is an altruistic software (I do not intend to charge my friends), so in a way, you have contributed to the cause.

Comment: Cool man this is awesome..wish I could give more that +1. very nice, thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 3):

This component is called autocomplete and is included in a so called swing extensions porject.

Just have a look at: http://swingx.java.net/
There is a webstart with demos: http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp

Answer (score 3):

- use AutoComplete JTextField placed into JToolBar / [MenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127463/714968), notice you must to sort ArrayList before usage,
- use undecoratted JDialog instead of JPopup (still have got a few important bugs),

  a) create only one JDialog with parent to the JTextField or JMenuBar or JFrame,

  b) always to search for getBounds from AutoComplete JTextField before visible JDialog  on the screen, this Bounds are for possitioning JDialog correctly on the screen

  c) wrap JDialog#setVisible(true) to the invokeLater()
- override [Escape for JDialog.setVisible(false)](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/)
- put there close / hide JButton to [avoiding overrive rest of important methods on focusLost](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) (this calendar have got excelent workaround on focusLost, mouseClick, etc ...., could it be very easy to replace calendar funcionality with result from Comparator, you have to download codesource)
- you can put there (my view) 6 / 9 / max 12 buttons, you can remove JButton Feels by setBackground(Color.white) for example, you cann't, please don't do it something with JDialog and these JButtons, you job will be only to setText("result from Comparator")
- in the case that your ArrayList for AutoComplete JTextField was sorted, then you have two choises

  a) easiest override bias from AutoComplete funcionality by add fils separate array for setText() for 6 / 9 / max 12 buttons on popup JDialog, if you setBackground(Color.white), then you don't care somehow about to hide JButtons without text

  b) another way could be to create own Comparator for searching (the same AutoComplete funcionality) first 6 / 9 / max 12 matches,
- for capturing an events from 6 / 9 / max 12 JButtons use [putClientProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472680/714968) or [EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968) or [Swing Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), where you only to test if text isEmpty :-),
- maybe `Swing Actions` could be the best of ways because its events are scallable and you can [enabled/disable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) (if JButtons text isEmpty) output from this Action by default

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `JComboBox` (see [Swing guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)) rather than a `JTextField`/`JList`.

Of course, then you have a drop-down button, but there are possible ways to deal with this - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822432/how-to-make-jcombobox-look-like-a-jtextfield).

Answer (score 1):

It would be something along these lines:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Component extends JComponent {
    private final static String[] terms = {"Jesus",
        "Jesus walks on water" //...
    };
    private static ArrayList<String> recent = new ArrayList<String>();

    JTextField jtf;
    JList jl;
    public Component(){
        // set up design
        jtf = new JTextField();
        jtf.setSize(this.getWidth() - 25, 25);
        this.add(jtf);
        //...
        // add key listeners
    }
    class Listener implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                // set next item on list
            }
            else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                // set previous item on list
            }
            else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                // search
            }
            else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                jtf.setText("");
            }
                                    else{
                                         // check list for matches
                                    }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is that all key events go to the component which has the focus. So what you need to do is identify keys which should really go to the other component and install a `KeyListener` to both.

In that listener, you can forward the events to the other component.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/531889/34088) how to dispatch an event to a new component. In your case, `source` must be the other component (the list, if your text field originally received the event and vice versa).